# How to Programmatically change the text layout of a Sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I'm trying to change the text layout of a SharePoint page using css rather than the browser editing tool. Ideally, I would like to apply the css direct into the .ASPX page? How can I achieve this? what are the id's associated with the text layout options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to add `<styles>` in the `head` section of generated HTML page. You can do this like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl styles = new HtmlGenericControl();
styles.TagName = "style";
styles.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
styles.InnerHtml = "myClass{color:#000000;}";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(style);
```